# Flutter How to make it automatically - (navigate to login) when http status code is 401

Tags: dart, flutter

Here is my previous codes.

```
    class mainScreen extends StatefulWidget 
    {

        Api api = new Api();
        override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () async{
              new Future.then(
                api.doSthA(),onError: (e) {      
                   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/login"); //this is repeat
                })
                new Future.then(
                api.doSthB(),onError: (e) {      
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/login"); //this is repeat
                 }
                )
            }
            );
      }
    }

    class Api
    {
        Future<dynamic> doSthA() async{
             return http
            .post(
              "url"
            )
            .then((http.Response res) {
                if(res.body.statusCode == 401){
                    throw new Exception("401");
                    }else{
                        return _decoder.convert(res);
                    }
            }
        }
        Future<dynamic> doSthB() async{
            similar with doSthA
        }

    }
```

I want it simplify to

```
new MaterialButton(
  onPressed: () async{
    new Future.then(api.doSthA())...
    new Future.then(api.doSthB())...
}
```

auto execute Navigator to login when api return 401.

Because Navigator must need widget's content.so I have no idea how to let it integrate with Api class.I want make Navigator be part of Api manager.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this when you want to navigate to login**

Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            context,
            '/login', (_) => false);

**Put this in build method**

Api api = Api(context: context)

**Api class**

```
class Api
{
  BuildContext context;
  Api({this.context});
}
```

**ApiCall Method**

```
if(res.statusCode == 401){
    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        '/login', (_) => false);
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, But I don't want make dependency of class Api and widget.
Which mean my api util must depend on the Widget Build like
    Widget build(context){
        Api api = Api(context: context)
    }

Comment: @derrickho Did you ever get this to work?  I have a similar problem.